# How can I store random_bytes in a database in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, encryption, libsodium

Inside of my migration I have a string column named `encryption_key` which looks like this:

```
$table->string('encryption_key')->unique();
```

I have a Controller that uses a trait to generate the encryption commands.

```
use LiveChat;

public function create()
{
    $this->header->insert([
        'encryption_key' => $this->issueKey()
    ]);

    $this->participants->insert([
        'chat_id' => DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId(),
        'user_id' => Auth::id()
    ]);

    return response(['status' => true, 'chat_id' => DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId()], 200)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}
```

The trait looks like this so far

```
trait LiveChat
{
    protected function issueKey()
    {
        return random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES);
    }
}
```

However, upon testing this I receive this error:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xFFX\x8Af\x1F$...' for column 'encryption_key' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `chat_headers` (`encryption_key`) values (ÿXŠf\x1F$¨ì™ÒÂø¢Ú!£”…¸ÈÍØ7ÿDå\x00Œ¿3ê))

If I use `dd()` to debug the response of `$this->issueKey()` I get something like this:

```
b"Bp,[\x1A\¢®ù·š(×g6ùs=l«j,©;_ó8ýòúÍ6"
```

I have tried to use `iconv()` like so

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII", $this->issueKey())
```

Which gives me

> iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

How can I store this key to use for future reference inside my DB?

Comment: `base64_encode` it. Use `base64_decode` when you access it from the database. A mutator/accessor function (see the docs) may be useful for this.

Comment: You are a star! I didn't think about using `base64_*` - which makes sense to do so. If you want to place an answer, I'll mark it as accepted @ceejayoz

Comment: or you could bin2hex(random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `base64_encode` it for storage, and undo it with `base64_decode`.

Putting together a set of [accessor and mutator functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators) will let you do this in an automatic fashion.

Comment: Why not use a binary column?  No size bloat and no manipulation outside SQL.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Fair enough. Add that as an answer!